# 'Selecting package versions' will continue to appear on the terminal and can not be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, webstorm

```
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>                |                                                                         Selecting package versions                /
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>                                                                                                                                                        Looking for packages
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>                                          Selecting package versions                /
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>                                                                                                        Looking for packages                      \
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>ing package versions                /                                                                => Meteor 1.6 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>clean                                                   Selecting package versions                /
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>meteor --versiong package versions                /
Meteor 1.2.1                                                                                                                                                                                                               Selecting package ver
sions                |eor mongo
D:\2016_3\2016_3_1g\Meteor\final>                r.                           strong text
```

---

I have a problem with re-running what I used with version 1.2.1.Also, when I checked the version, I verified the 1.2.1 version without any problem.

Comment: What steps have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: you will find dozens of similar reports on the web - see https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-not-working-on-windows-7-struck-at-selecting-package-versions/14931/9, for example. In most cases, `meteor update` helps